# firefox profile setting not updating correctly through selenium

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, page-object-gem

I am trying to set the firefox profile so that all links will open in the same tab when running my selenium tests.

I have found the setting required to do this, howvever when the program runs it is not being set to the value i want, whereas other values are.

Heres my code

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction'] = 0
profile['browser.link.open_newwindow'] = 1
@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

the loaded broswer page has the 'browser.link.open_newwindow' set to 2, which is not the default setting and the browser indicates that the value 2 has been user set, even though it is not what I have set it to be

does anyone know why this maybe happening? does selenium or the page-object-gem write this value?

Comment: it looks like selenium sets it to 2 on start up, in the file selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension/prefs.json

is it possible to over write this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Capybara, have this in your `features/support.env.rb` file:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction'] = 0
  profile['browser.link.open_newwindow'] = 1
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end
```

Comment: im not, and the issue is specific to the ''browser.link.open_newwindow' value, all other values i can set are setting correctly